# microSDXC responding to SPI ACMD41 with SD mode?

Tags: arduino, spi, microchip, sd

For a project I am working on, I need to access raw blocks from a microSDXC 128GB card (SanDisk) using SPI, and I am writing my own code to do this. I am using a PIC18F87K22 microchip to talk to the SD, and the clock at initialization is 250kHz. Currently, my main problem is that the SDXC cards, once being used for a while, have a tendency to stop cooperating with my initialize function.  SDHC cards of multiple kinds have worked, but the SDXC is not as agreeable.

My SDXC card responses fall apart in the CMD55/ACMD41 loop during initialization. The card will respond for a while with 0x1 (as expected), and then the MISO line will go silent. Eventually the SDXC stops responding at all, and then after one or two more command attempts (55/41), it appears that the SD card starts responding like it is in SD mode, and ACMD41 just results in the OCR register being sent as the response.

Interestingly, if I send a CMD0 next, I still get a SPI response. In fact, I can send the whole initialization process again, and I get correct SPI responses until a little while through the CMD55/ACMD41 loop, when the microSD starts responding in SD mode again. (Initialization is 80 clock cycles with CS high, CMD0, CMD8, then I get stuck at CMD55/ACMD41.)

Below is a logic processor screenshot of when the SD card switches from responding with SPI mode to responding with SD mode during initialization.

[image: logic processor screenshot of microSDXC switching modes]

The Arduino SPI.h library (I'm using Arduino Uno) has been successful in reinitializing the cards which I can't. I've recorded the Arduino communication with the SD card from the moment the Arduino is plugged in to the computer until the initialization is complete, and although I've imitated this process in my own code, I still cannot initialize these cards without the Arduino. After being initialized with the Arduino, the SDXC card can be initialized perfectly with my C code, until it stops again after I have worked with it for a little while (initializing/reading/writing is all I do), and the cycle continues.

tl;dr My microSDXC cards don't always initialize with my SPI initialization function even though my microSDHC cards do. It appears that they sometimes start responding to my initialization CMD55/ACMD41 loop in SD mode, but sending a CMD0 in the midst of this causes a SPI response, and I cannot figure out how this is happening.

What could be causing this shift in the card's mode? Is there a difference between microSDXC and microSDHC in SPI communication that I need to account for? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the CS does not toggle at all between commands, but simply stays low? That's not how it's supposed to work, right?

Comment: I've tried it both ways (with and without toggling CS), and for initialization, it hasn't made a difference, but I believe you're right that normally toggling CS is the best practice way to do things.